# How to make a good functions structure

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, return-value

I'm using Express, and in somewhere i need to do this

1. get from some API json with senders
2. get from some API json with receivers
3. render page with both of them

So I rly cant understand how to build this function... I mean

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('nodes/index', {senders: helper.getServices(), receivers: helper.getReceivers()}
```

And my functions looks like

```
this.getSenders = () => {    
    var options = { ... some opts }
    request(options)
      .then(function (body) {
        return body
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
}
```

With this structures page renders before data will be returned from functions... 
How should I organize my code to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asynchronous functions you need to wait for result from API before rendering view. It will be faster if you use `async` for handling those 2 asynchronous requests

Router

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {helper.getServices(callback)},
        function(callback) {helper.getReceivers(callback)}
    ], function done(err, results){
        if(error){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        res.render('nodes/index', {
            senders: results[0],
            receivers: results[1]
        })
     })
 })
```

function:

```
this.getSenders = (callback) => {    
    var options = { ... some opts }
    return request(options)
      .then(function (body) {
          callback(null,body)
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          callback(err, null)
      })
}
```